# Using htaccess to grant access to index file when user requests directory URL

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I would like to use htaccess to allow access to the index file plus a few others in a directory (index.php) but require a user/pass for everything else in the directory. Right now I have:

```
AuthName "SomeServer"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
AuthType Basic
<FilesMatch "(index.php)|(login.php)">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

This allows users to access index.php and login.php and denies the rest of the directory. However, whenever a user requests the directory without the index.php in the URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/dir
```

The user is prompted to login. However, if the user goes here:

```
http://www.example.com/dir/index.php
```

Then index.php is displayed without a login prompt.

What do I need to change to allow the user to go to http://www.example.com/dir and be directed to http://www.example.com/dir/index.php without prompting for a login while still requiring a login for anything else in the directory?

Update: not sure it matters, but I switched the authentication to use mod_auth_mysql. Still using the same  section of my htaccess file and still facing the same problem.

Comment: Are you interesting to add exception only for particular directory - /dir?

Comment: No, just those 2 files. All other directories need to be locked down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /vhosts/default

    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /vhosts/default>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location ~ ^/dir/(index|login)\.php$>
        Allow from all
        Satisfy any
    </Location>

    <Location ~ ^/dir/?$>
        Allow from all
        Satisfy any
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Make some basic tests

```
# curl -I http://localhost/
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 10:03:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="SomeServer"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

# curl -I http://localhost/index.php
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 10:03:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="SomeServer"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1


# curl -I http://localhost/dir/index.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 10:03:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.16
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


# curl -I http://localhost/dir/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 10:03:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.16
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


# curl -I http://localhost/dir/some_file.php
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 10:04:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="SomeServer"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

# curl -I http://localhost/dir
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 10:04:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Location: http://localhost/dir/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is there any way to do this through htaccess instead of through the Apache config file? Or does it have to be in the virtual hosts section?

Comment: Unfortunately Location can be used only in server config/virtual host context - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location